# Symfony / Doctrine ManyToMany with conditions and limit

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, twig, many-to-many, symfony

I've created a concept of a Person model having many e-mails. I also have a Company model that can share the same e-mails with People (Person model).

In short:
People OneToMany PeopleEmail ManyToOne Email (classic manytomany unidirectional with a join table)

```
people { id, firstname, lastname, created }
people_emails { person_id, email_id, main, created }
emails { id, email, created }
```

as well as:

```
companies { id, name, employee_count, created }
companies_emails { company_id, email_id, main, created }
emails { id, email, created }
```

The problem is, that I'd like to store a boolean value called "main" in the join table as follows:

```
person_id | email_id | main | created
    8     |     5    | true | 2014-10-21 16:54:21
```

...so that I can do this:

```
Mark Wilson (Person) has 5 emails.
3 of them are his company e-mails (shared): contact@company.com, office@company.com, it@company.com
2 of them are his own.
1 he answers only in his leisure time
1 is his MAIN email: i.e. m.wilson@company.com
```

Instead of fetching all those 5 emails, I'd like to easily get the primary email just as if it was a regular Person model column:

```
firstname: Mark (string)
lastname: Wilson (string)
emails: (array)
primary_email: (email object)
```

I cannot store the "main" property anywhere else, as I want to point, that the relation between Mark and his Email is "main", not the email itself.

Now, I do have this value stored, but the problem is, how to make an entity property like:

```
class Person {

    (...)

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Email")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="people_emails",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="email_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $primary_email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Email")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="people_emails",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="email_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)} // A condition?
     *      )
     */
    private $emails;

    public function getPrimaryEmail() {
        return $this->primary_email; // Single row limit?
    }

    public function getEmails() {
        return $this->emails;
    }

    (...)
}
```

The thing is, I would really love to have it as an entity property, just for use in any case possible without the need to write custom repostory functions for the whole Person model.

Or maybe that is a completely wrong way. I'd like to use that property in Twig like:

```
{{person.primary_email.email}}
```

To sum up:
I'd like to store a ManyToMany single row relationship depending on joinTable column.

How to do that?

Comment: If you want to store additional data within the join table you should consider making a new entity that is representing the join table and add the one-to-many and many-to-one relations between those entities. And to retrieve your primary email you can either use the Doctrine Criteria or filter the collection of emails yourself by looping through and return the right one within your Person entity.

Comment: Looping is out of the question as I want to literally fetch the results based on joinTable criteria. Thx

Comment: Looping being out of the question is your mistake here. Looping is not that much slower, and there is no way to do what you want in doctrine, especially not considering your database model doesn't actually restrict having multiple mains. The only other solution is to not use the join table for the primary email by making the primary property a direct ManyToOne referencing the Email entity.

Comment: Whether you map or filter your Collections as within TFennis answer, this is pretty much looping through your result set. And you can't really cut the JoinTable to Entity away as you need the extra properties and to access them you will need the entity. The PrimaryEmail which is fetched from another table is not able to be stored like some sort of property of your entity. You could always retrieve the data like fetching: EAGER, to always fetch the emails on fetching a User or Company object. So TFennis answer is neat solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this and there are also many critical things to say about your design choices. Either way here is an example of one way you could achieve this using two join tables (you need two if you want to use foreign keys).

```
<?php

interface AddressLink
{
    public function getEmail();
    public function isMain();
}


trait EmailAddressOwner
{
    protected abstract function getAddressLinks();

    public function getPrimaryEmailAddress()
    {
        return $this->getAddressLinks()->filter(function (AddressLink $addressLink) {
            return $addressLink->isMain();
        })->first();
    }

    public function getEmailAddresses()
    {
        return $this->getAddressLinks()->map(function (AddressLink $addressLink) {
            return $addressLink->getEmail();
        });
    }
}

class PersonEmailAddress implements AddressLink
{
    private $person; // ManyToOne
    private $email; // ManyToOne
    private $main; // bool
}

class CompanyEmailAddress implements AddressLink
{
    private $company; // ManyToOne
    private $email; // ManyToOne
    private $main; // bool
}


class Email
{
    private $id;
    private $address;
}

class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonEmailAddress")
     */
    private $emailAddressLinks;

    use EmailAddressOwner;

    public function getAddressLinks()
    {
        return $this->emailAddressLinks;
    }

}

class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyEmailAddress")
     */
    private $emailAddressLinks;

    use EmailAddressOwner;

    public function getAddressLinks()
    {
        return $this->emailAddressLinks;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to include one `ManyToMany` relation to your `Email` entity and one `ManyToOne` relation for the primary e-mail address.

To answer you question in the comments if in twig you do

```
{{ person.primaryEmail.email }}
```

It wil actually call the `getPrimaryEmail()` method on your Person object. Which you can implement like I've outlined above. That way you don't need to have this extra property.

Comment: I've added some clarification. The thing is, the OTM & MTO already exist. The problem is how to "use" this relation in the simplest possible way.

Comment: What I mean, an annotation of this kind would be very appreciated: ORM\WhereJoinColumn(name="main", value="1")

Comment: I updated my answer in short `{{ person.primaryEmail }}` will actually call `person->getPrimaryEmail()` which you can implement with the `filter()->first()` like in my answer.